# How to get the browser src dynamically in xul

Tags: javascript, xul

I have a browser control:

```
<browser flex="1" id="browser" src="http://www.google.com" type="content-primary" tooltip="browserTooltip"/>
```

How i get the src of the browser, according to the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getElementById("browser").getAttribute("src")
```